# What does the "+" , "*", "!" sign next to a branch name indicate in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-branch

In VS Code there is a **"+"** sign next to my branch name. What does that mean?

[image]

Comment: There is also an asterisk next to the branch name, and it sounds pretty the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768651/what-does-alongside-a-branch-name-in-vs-code-mean . I don't use VSCode, but did you try to correlate the output of `git status` and the presence of `+` next to the branch name (say, the number of commits ahead/behind the upstream)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/6e85d2b51ef005941279a762c541d93eaf0dc35e/extensions/git/src/repository.ts#L2299-L2301) reveals that:

- `*` indicates you have unstaged changes (not been added yet)
- `+` indicates you have staged changes (added, but not commited)
- `!` indicates unmerged conflicts

There can also be `Rebasing` [at the end](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/05e2b0b0f1049bf7a46cb9ce72c52dfa85b9271d/extensions/git/src/statusbar.ts#L50), when you are in the middle of a rebase.

---

So, if you see `*+`, then `git status` should show some staged and some unstaged changes.